# Connector for dropbox

Tags: java, dropbox, connector

I am developing a connector for Dropbox. I have to enter the URL manually into the browser which is generated by the program, and clicking on the allow button is also manual. Please help me figure out how to do this automatically; the browser should not be opened, and only one user interaction should be necessary.

Here's my code:

```
import com.dropbox.core.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
    // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
    final String APP_KEY = "; //redacted
    final String APP_SECRET = ""; //redacted

    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
                Locale.getDefault().toString());
    DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);

    // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
    String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
    System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
    System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
    System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
    String code = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();

    // This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
    DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
    String accessToken = authFinish.accessToken;

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);

    System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);

    File inputFile = new File("working-draft.txt");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    try {
      DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
                    DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
      System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
      inputStream.close();
    }

    DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("/");
    System.out.println("Files in the root path:");
    for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
      System.out.println("  " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
    }

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("magnum-opus.txt");
    try {
      DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/magnum-opus.txt", null,
                    outputStream);
      System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
      outputStream.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are askin?

Comment: @fish2000: Here i have to explicitly open the browser and manually enter the browser and then copy the code into console all these things are manually. I want the user interaction must not be more than once means if once the user run the program after that it will automatically perform all the operation. how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way for a user to authorize an app is to do so via OAuth in the browser. So you will not be able to avoid opening the browser the first time the user authorizes your app. (After the initial auth, you can store and reuse the access token, but that first time they run the app, they'll have to log in to Dropbox in the browser.)

Comment: there is any way in which i can provide the authentication detail in program itself and it can automatically fetch the access token from URL

Comment: Can we keep the browser opening in memory rather than opening manually and is it possible to authorize the application programatically instead of manually

Comment: No to your first question, and probably no to your second question, though I can't be sure. (I don't think I fully understand what you're asking.)

Comment: Mine second Qu. Is  in Dropbox we have  to provide manually access (click on allow button and copy the authorization code and paste into console) to the application. is it possible to provide automatic access by using some program  instead of manually access

Answer (score 0):

OAuth demands a two step process.
You have to register your application with DropBox first. Box will give you a string which you should include in your call during user authorization.

If the user authorizes your application to use their resources then they will give you a token, which you have to use on future calls.

Take a read on how OAuth works: https://www.pingidentity.com/resource-center/oauth-essentials.cfm

and

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api